# GCD Iteratively in x86 intel Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, greatest-common-divisor

I am trying to find GCD iteratively in x86 assembly.  Somehow, the loop keeps terminating after the first iteration because remainder=0.  Any ideas why?

```
;while r > 0 do
;   Set b = a
;   Set a = r
;   Set r = b % a
;Output a


calculation_loop:
    cmp     remainder, 0                    ;check if remainder is 0
    je      end_of_calc                     ;if it is, value in intA is GCD

    mov     ecx, intA                       ;set b = a
    mov     intB, ecx

    mov     ecx, remainder                  ;set a = r
    mov     intA, ecx

    mov     edx, 0                          ;clearing remainder

    mov     ecx, intA                       ;process remainder and store in variable
    div     ecx
    mov     remainder, edx


    mov     eax, remainder
    call    WriteInt
    call    Crlf

    jmp     calculation_loop

end_of_calc:

    call    Crlf
    mov     eax, intA
    mov     edx, OFFSET outputPrompt
    call    WriteString
    call    WriteInt
    call    Crlf
```

Answer (score 0):

I bet `remainder` is set to 0 before you reach the first iteration of `calculation_loop`, and that's why it's jumping out of `calculation_loop` immediately. That's your problem, but what about a solution?

You should order your code differently, so it functions like a `do-while` instead of a `while` loop. I reordered your instructions, so that the code functions like a `do-while` loop:

```
; calculation loop
calculation_loop:
    ; set b to a
    mov ecx, intA
    mov intB, ecx
    ; set a to r
    mov ecx, remainder
    mov intA, ecx
    ; clear remainder (I don't think this is nessesary, can't say for sure)
    mov edx, 0
    ;process remainder and store in variable
    mov ecx, intA                       
    div ecx
    mov remainder, edx
    ; write data
    mov eax, remainder
    call WriteInt
    call Crlf
    ; if the remainder != 0, go again
    cmp remainder, 0
    jne calculation_loop
```

Notice how I do the remainder checking jump at the end of the loop, *after* the remainder has been calculated. Hopefully this solves your problem.

Note: I don't remember how integer division is done in x86, so I can't say if any of the other code is potentially erroneous. But I do think I solved the problems to do with the ordering of your conditional jumps.

Finally, one more tip. If you're writing this kind of number crunching code, a great way to find bugs is stepping through your code instruction at a time and seeing how the registers change (via. a debugger). If you're not already doing this, I highly suggest it.